# Search in an Array Typeorm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I implemented search using filters(that are optional) in typeOrm (Postgres)

```
        queryBuilder.where({
            ...(filter.givenBy && { fromUser: sender.id }),
            ...(filter.receivedBy && { toUser: receiver.id }),
            ...(filter.endDate && { createdAt: LessThanOrEqual(filter.endDate) }),
            ...(filter.startDate && { createdAt: MoreThanOrEqual(filter.startDate) }),
            ...(filter.startDate && filter.endDate && { createdAt: Between(filter.startDate, filter.endDate) })
        })
```

previously `toUser` is of type UUID so it worked. migration has been written to convert `toUser` to an Array of UUID (UUID[ ]). how should I update the query builder to search in the array when the filter `toUser` is given?

previously:

```
          |              to_user                   |
          -----------------------------------------
          |   652afb8a-6bf3-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002 |
```

Currently

```
          |                                    to_user                                     |
           ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          |   {652afb8a-6bf3-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002, 99e53e12-6bf3-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002 }|
```

**Update:**
I did something like this

```
queryBuilder.where({
            ...(filter.givenBy && { fromUser: sender.id }),
            ...(filter.endDate && { createdAt: LessThanOrEqual(filter.endDate) }),
            ...(filter.startDate && { createdAt: MoreThanOrEqual(filter.startDate) }),
            ...(filter.startDate && filter.endDate && { createdAt: Between(filter.startDate, filter.endDate) })
        })

if(filter.receivedBy){
            queryBuilder.andWhere('t.to_user && :data', { data:[receiver.id]})
        }
```

It's working but I am getting:
`(when toUser = 652afb8a-6bf3-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002)`

```
{

     "createdAt": "2022-11-24T10:33:00.914Z",
     "updatedAt": "2022-11-24T10:33:00.914Z",
     "id": "657481cc-0aed-4849-9f86-a2a7ece30a18",
     "fromUser": "12b0b72c-6bf4-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002",
     "toUser": [
          "652afb8a-6bf3-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002",
          "99e53e12-6bf3-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002"
      ],
      "quantity": 9,
      "message": "test110"
}
```

But, I don't want that extra value in `toUser` . i want something like this:

```
{
            "createdAt": "2022-11-24T10:33:00.914Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-24T10:33:00.914Z",
            "id": "657481cc-0aed-4849-9f86-a2a7ece30a18",
            "fromUser": "12b0b72c-6bf4-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002",
            "toUser": [
                "652afb8a-6bf3-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002"
            ],
            "quantity": 9,
            "message": "test110"
        }
```